# DNS resolve not working on virtualbox VM when VPN is switched on host

Tags: networking, virtualbox, virtual-machine, vpn

I have Windows 10 host and Ubuntu Server guest vm on Virtualbox. I have OpenVPN client on the Windows host. The guest vm is set to NAT network(not NAT) type.

Whenever the client is switched on, traffic from host gets routed via server the OpenVPN client has connected to. But I immediately lose DNS lookup/resolve in the guest VM (Internet works fine in both guest vm & host)

If VPN client is off, everything (internet, dns lookup) works fine in my guest VM (and host anyways).

Any suggestions on how to mitigate this?

Answer (score 0):

This occurs (often with Microsoft VPN) because the VPN setup forces all traffic including Internet traffic through the tunnel.

You need a VPN client that supports Split Tunnel.

See if the VPN vendor support offers a method for split tunnel,or use a different VPN client.

If the VPN is your employer's setup, you may need to use the Virtual Machine at a time when you can turn the VPN client off.

Here is a resource for split tunnel with [Open VPN](https://openvpn.net/for/split-tunneling-with-access-server/#:%7E:text=In%20the%20Admin%20Web%20UI,networks%20will%20traverse%20the%20VPN.).

Comment: I've updated my question. I'm using OpenVPN with config file to connect to the access server

Comment: It is likely the client APP you are using and it is not set (or cannot be set) for split tunnel.  That stops internet outside the VPN tunnel when VPN is connected.   Try this article about split tunnel.   ......   https://openvpn.net/for/split-tunneling-with-access-server/#:~:text=In%20the%20Admin%20Web%20UI,networks%20will%20traverse%20the%20VPN.